# Symfony json_login not working

Tags: json, symfony, authentication, symfony-3.3

I wanted to try the new json_login with Symfony 3.3..followed the docs with a clean project..but the firewall totally ignores the json_login section. I am receiving an error saying the controller did not return a response.

I am pasting my security.yml bellow ..

```
security:
providers:
    db_provider:
        entity:
            class: IgsemAuthBundle:User
            property: email
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_USER:        IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
encoders:
    Igsem\AuthBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        provider: db_provider
        json_login:
            check_path: check
access_control:
    - { path: ^/secure, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I also have a controller with with the check route annotated:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/check", name="check")
 */
public function checkAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
{
}
```

I tried to play around with the path, used name but also relative path login or /login and some other combinations..al with the same

thanks for the help

Answer (score 6):

This isn't explicitly mentioned in the documentation, but for this configuration to work, you need to have your request to specify `"Content-Type": "application/json"` header. Otherwise requests just pass through to controller without being handled by security listener.

Also, whether it's by design or not, you still want to implement controller's response, since - at least on my Symfony 3.3.14 - `Response` was not created as stated in docs. So while User got authenticated (or errored out on wrong credentials) I still needed to design `Response` myself (which is ok for me, at least I retain control over response format/structure).

Answer (score -1):

Until the Symfony docs are not updated, the json_login option requires a success_handler and a failure_handler..otherwise it will throw an error..it is not enough to just define a target route..I already raised a PR it should be fixed soon

Comment: This does not fix the issue for me and i am not able to find the PR, you mentioned.